# Rust: the usage of "self" when bringing paths into scope

Tags: rust

```rust
mod front_of_house {
    pub mod hosting {
        pub fn add_to_waitlist() {}
    }
}

use self::front_of_house::hosting;

pub fn eat_at_restaurant() {
    hosting::add_to_waitlist();
    hosting::add_to_waitlist();
    hosting::add_to_waitlist();
}
```

The code is from [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-04-bringing-paths-into-scope-with-the-use-keyword.html). In this case, if using the relative path, why bother to use `self`? I find that `use front_of_house::hosting` works well here.

So, any necessary reason to introduce `self` here?

Comment: matter of taste

Answer (score 2):

The outcome of `use front_of_house::hosting` depends on the context. If the crate root contains `extern crate front_of_house` or `front_of_house` is a dependency in `Cargo.toml`, this will refer to `hosting` in that crate. In your case, however, there is the local module `front_of_house`, which takes priority over external crates. Conveniently, it's located just before the code that uses it, so it's obvious that it's the actual module being used. In larger files, however, there is a chance that the source of a module is ambiguous, i.e. if there is a dependency named the same as a local module. In that case, the extra `self` adds clarity to the code, helping you differentiate between dependencies and local modules. If, in that case, you wanted to use the dependency, you'd `use ::front_of_house::hosting`, which unconditionally refers to the dependency and fails if there isn't one named like that.